# React Promise - confusion in coding

Tags: reactjs, es6-promise

I am new to react, and trying to follow a tutorial of Promises. I merged the two files into one as below for convenience. However, I am totally lost as to how to display the desired images. I copied the last bit from another react application.

```
import React from 'react'

function DemoPromise2() {

    function loadImage(url) {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            let image = new Image();

            image.onload = function () {
                resolve(image);
            };

            image.onerror = function () {
                let message = "Could not load image at " + url;
                reject(new Error(message));
            };

            image.src = url;
        });
    }
    // export default loadImage;

    let addImg = (src) => {
        let imgElement = document.createElement("img");
        imgElement.src = src;
        document.body.appendChild(imgElement);
    };

    Promise.all([
      loadImage("images/img1.jpg"),
      loadImage("images/img2.jpg"),
      loadImage("images/img3.jpg"),
      loadImage("images/img4.jpg"),
    ])
      .then((images) => {
        images.forEach((img) => addImg(img.src));
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        // handle error later
      });

    
         return (
                    <div className="App">
                       Demo Promise2 -
                       <br />
                       

????  Question :: how can I display images here??


                    </div>
                );
                       
}

export default DemoPromise2;
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: You should learn about the `useState` and `useEffect` hooks

Answer (score 1):

@Evert is correct, you need to load this into state to show the images.

**TL;DR:** Click **Run code snippet** below to see the code in action.

--

**Longer Explanation:**

**`useState`** will allow the data to be accessed with the component and allow it to be persisted within it. You either get the value with it's name or setValue to update it.

Ex:

```
const [myvalue, setMyvalue] = useState('defaultValue');
```

**`useEffect`** is use as another React but specifically for when state get modified and given that you give specific things to look for (or watch as an array)

Example Nothing To Watch:

```
useEffect(() => {
console.log('CODE IS RUN ONLY ONCE, Nothing to watch except when component loads');
}, []);
```

Example State To Watch:

```
const [value, setValue] = useState('watch this');
useEffect(() => {
console.log('RUN EACH TIME value is updated including first time set');
}, [value]);
```

**Code:**

```js
// main.js

// for your code use: import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
const { useState, useEffect } = React;

const App = () => {
  // State / Props
  const [images, setImages] = useState([]);
  
  // Load Images Function
  const loadImage = (url) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      let image = new Image();
       
      image.onload = () => {
        resolve(image);
      };
      
      image.onerror = () => {
        let message = `Could not load ${url}`;
        reject(new Error(message));
      };
      
      image.src = url;
       
     });
  };
  
  // Hook to use when the component is loaded and ready
  // Equivalent to something like window.onload
  useEffect(() => {
     Promise.all([
      loadImage('https://picsum.photos/seed/picsum/200/200'),
      loadImage('https://picsum.photos/200/200')
    ])
    .then((data) => {
      setImages(data);
    })
    .catch((error) => console.log('ERROR', error));
  }, []);
  
  return <div><h1>My Images</h1><p>Images Loaded: {images.length}</p>{images.map((img, index) => <img key={`img-${index}`} src={img.getAttribute('src')} />)}</div>;
};

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.querySelector('#root'));
```

```html
<body>
<div id="root"></div>

<script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6/babel.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/babel" src="main.js"></script>
</body>
```

**====== CLARIFICATIONS ======**

**Question:**

```
const [images, setImages] = useState([]); ???????????? the above defines const 'images'. Where is 'images' value modified? where is it receiving values/images?
```

**Answer:**

Think of this part as [destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) from a variable that's an array, but you're getting the `getter` and `setter` from `useState`.

The same way you would destructure an array like:

```
const myArray = [1, 2];
const [firstValue, secondValue] = myArray;
// firstValue = 1
// secondValue = 2
```

But instead of just plain values, you're getting the equivalent of functions returned to **`get`** the value and **`set`** a new value.

Note that [`useState`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html) is defined by React.

With that in mind, `images` is updated (set) here:

```
    .then((data) => {
      setImages(data);
    })
```

---

**Question:**

```
2. let image = new Image(); ???????? whats the purpose of this sttmt? 'let image = new image()' ??? such was used to set an instance of a class but why is it used for a function? ????????
```

**Answer:**

[`new Image()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLImageElement/Image) is a base function baked into the browser, and would be typically be used for creating a new `<img>` with some event handling, or potentially other custom functionality.

Technically you do not need to use `new Image()` here if you're just going to rely on the browser to load the images naturally.

In the case of your initial code, the functionality exists to do something when the image is done loading, or handle errors in a specific way, but there isn't really any code except for resolving a promise.

What you would do is something like:

```
image.onload = () => {
   // Images is loaded send message to custom logging software
   // OR Image is loaded which works like a tracking pixel sent a message
   // OR Image is loaded, append it to DOM and perform a fade in animation
   resolve(image);
};
```

Sometimes you would just use this function to handle ordering images in a sequential way, or control the sequence of loading and animations.

On in the case of your code, wait until all the images are loaded, then show the page vs. loading them one by one natively in the browser.

---

**Question:**

```
3. image.onload = () => {resolve(image); 'image.onload' is just a const , will it hold the 'image'?
```

**Answer:**

It does not hold the image, this is just an event function that is defined by [Image](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLImageElement/Image) to handle when the image is done loading. So it's a predefined function that is called by Image, but defined by you.

---

**Question:**

```
?4. image.src = url .. ??
```

**Answer:**

This is the part of Image that starts the whole process, that's why it's defined at the end.

The code is saying.

```js
// Before you begin you're going to be getting an image
let image = new Image();

// Before we load the image, I want to tell you how to handle it once
// it loads successfully
image.onload = function {
   // custom instructions
};

// Before we load the image, I want to tell you how to handle it
// in case things go wrong
image.onerror = function {
   // custom instructions
}

// Ok, we're good to go, start the process, here's the url
image.src = url; // https://picsum.photos/seed/picsum/200/200
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the kind response. Could I request you to clarify some points for me to get them clear in my head, please.

?1.   const [images, setImages] = useState([]);
  
  the above defines const 'images'. Where is 'images' value modified? where is it receiving values/images? 

?2.   let image = new Image();
        whats the purpose of this sttmt? 'l such sttmt was used to set an instance of a class but why is it used for a function?
?3.       image.onload = () => {resolve(image);
 'image.onload' is just a const , will it hold the 'image'?
?4. image.src = url  .. ??

Comment: @nktoronto Check the new section called **CLARIFICATIONS** in the answer.

Comment: PS if it helped, please don't forget to mark this as the answer to the question.

Comment: Thk again explaining it v well. May I request a few followup questions:

4.  after Promise ...
 ])
      .then((images) => {
        images.forEach((img) => addImg(img.src));
'img' is an element type but as a variable should  it be defined?
2.   Promise.all([
      loadImage('https://picsum.photos/seed/picsum/200/200'),  
fn loadImage is called and stores image in 'image'. when called second time, does it save the  'image' from the 1st call separately?
3. how is this sttmt working:
then((images) => {
        images.forEach((img) => addImg(img.src));
4. how to print the images?

Comment: moreover: 
I started with a react bootstrap (npm create-react-app). Do we need the following :
<body>
<div id="root"></div>

<script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6/babel.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/babel" src="main.js"></script>
</body>

Comment: You would not need that extra code, that is only for me to get React working in StackOverflow. The only you you need to leave in is `<div id="root"><div>` if you're using `create-react-app`.

Comment: @nktoronto Would you be able to mark this as the correct answer, it would greatly be appreciated :)